# Change selected cell image based on sections

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I have 3 sections in my `tableView`, I want single selection like radio buttons in each section. My code working for single section, but not for multiple sections. I'm not using any custom buttons for this, directly using `contentView` `imageView` to set images and `didSelectRowAt indexPath:` for selection

My code is

```
cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "radio1")//Deselected state
cell?.imageView?.tag = indexPath.row
cell?.contentView.viewWithTag(8888)
if (selectedIndexPath != nil && selectedIndexPath?.section == 0 && selectedIndexPath?.row == indexPath.row) {
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "radio2")//Selected state
} else {
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "radio1")//Deselected state
}
if selectedIndexPath?.section == 1 {
}
if selectedIndexPath?.section == 2 {
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPath = indexPath//Save selected indexpath
    print(selectedIndexPath)
    tblView.reloadData()
```

The above code getting result like

When I select (Section1, Row0) automatically (Section2, Row0)also selected. I want select rows individually based on sections.

Comment: Why won't you use button with states? I am very uncleared with your question.

Comment: can you show this how do u crteated this `selectedIndexPath`

Comment: No use of buttons, because of we have imageView to show image and didSelectrow at index path function for selection.

Comment: @Anbu.Karthik, var selectedIndexPath:IndexPath? created globally

Comment: What is the issue .. changing image? or not able to select multi section.. button also have image property .. for radio button..use uIbutton bcz its more handy.

Comment: @ dahiya_boy, I think button also will get the same problem, because of I'm using multiple sections here. For single section it's ok, for multiple sections how to add tags.

Comment: @ Anbu.Karthik, hay dear  Anbu.Karthik can you please solve my one more question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373430/twitter-error-your-credentials-do-not-allow-access-to-this-resource/55539202#55539202

Comment: @  dahiya_boy, dear   dahiya_boy can you please solve my one more question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55373430/twitter-error-your-credentials-do-not-allow-access-to-this-resource/55539202#55539202

Comment: @iOS why are you complicating yourself? why dont you just use all rows? and show it like its group of sections and rows in UI?

Comment: @ Harjot Singh, I'm using sections. It has 3 sections

Comment: @iOS why don't you use all rows?

Comment: @ Harjot Singh, no those are different types

Comment: @iOS different types? That you know but not your code, you can use all rows and differentiate it based on your requirements.

Comment: @ dahiya_boy actually if I use only buttons user need to tap only on buttons. This is filter View, so size of buttons is so small. That's why I'm given selection for rows.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a single section tableview you can use `selectedIndexPath` to store selected indexPath. For multiple section tableview you need an array of indexPaths

```
var selectedIndexPathArr: [IndexPath?] = Array(repeating: nil, count: 3)//3 is number of sections
```

Then in didSelect method store selected indexpath in its section index

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPathArr[indexPath.section] = indexPath//save selected indexpath depends section
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In didDeselectRowAt method remove seaved index path from the array

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    selectedIndexPathArr[indexPath.section] = nil//delete selected indexpath depends section
    tableView.reloadData()
}
```

In cellForRowAt method compare current indexpath with the indexpath from the array depends on the current section

```
if selectedIndexPathArr[indexPath.section] == indexPath {
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "radio2")//Selected state
} else {
    cell?.imageView?.image = UIImage.init(named: "radio1")//Deselected state
}
```

[image]

Then you can get selected indexpath for each section

You'll get `nil` if no cell is selected in particular section

```
print(selectedIndexPathArr[0])//first section selected indexpath
print(selectedIndexPathArr[1])//second section selected indexpath
print(selectedIndexPathArr[2])//third section selected indexpath
```